# Create bubble plot in R (ggplot2) with custom labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a bubble plot in R using ggplot. The Y axis denotes the number of positive associations from 7 different studies (study 1-7), and on the X axis the years the studies were performed. The bubbles should be equal to the value of positive associations and display the number of positive associations in the center of the bubbles. So far I have managed to plot this. However, I am having trouble with the legends. I want the legends to be to the right of the plot. One dot for each study and the number of cases and controls included in the studies should be displayed, instead of study number.

The data can be created with the following code:

```
study_data <- data.frame(
  Year = c(2007, 2011, 2013, 2014, 2016, 2018, 2022),
  Positive_Associations = c(0, 2, 15, 17, 25, 40, 95),
  CaseSize = c(267, 5000, 12000, 15000, 19000, 26000, 37000),
  ControlSize = c(270, 8600, 21000, 50000, 95000, 403000, 1400000),
  Study = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
)
```

The code I have used so far is and the last part is my attempt to display the intended legends, although it for some reason does not work.

```
# Convert "Study" to a character factor for color assignment
study_data$Study <- as.factor(study_data$Study)

# Create custom legend labels combining CaseSize and ControlSize
legend_labels <- paste("Cases:", study_data$CaseSize, ", Controls:", study_data$ControlSize)

# Create the bubble plot
p <- ggplot(study_data, aes(x = Year, y = Positive_Associations, size = Positive_Associations, color = Study)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.7) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Positive_Associations), color = "black", vjust = 0.5, size = 3) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(3, 12)) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
  labs(title = "Evolution of studies",
       x = "Year",
       y = "Number of Positive_Associations") +
  theme_minimal()

# Add legend to the right with custom labels
p + theme(legend.position = "right") +
  guides(
    color = guide_legend(
      label.position = "right",
      title = NULL,  # Remove the legend title
      override.aes = list(
        size = 5,
        alpha = 1,
        breaks = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
        labels = legend_labels
      )
    ),
    size = "none"  # Remove the size legend
  ) +
  labs(size = NULL)  # Remove the legend title for size
```

Also, ideally each bubble should be some what larger/scaled up proportionally so there is less white space on the plot.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `labels` to your `scale_color_brewer`. To make sure you left-align the labels, you could use `legend.text.align = 0` to your `theme` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
# Create the bubble plot
p <- ggplot(study_data, aes(x = Year, y = Positive_Associations, size = Positive_Associations, color = Study)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.7) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Positive_Associations), color = "black", vjust = 0.5, size = 3) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(3, 12)) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2",
                     labels = legend_labels) +
  labs(title = "Evolution of studies",
       x = "Year",
       y = "Number of Positive_Associations") +
  theme_minimal()

# Add legend to the right with custom labels
p + theme(legend.position = "right",
          legend.text.align = 0) +
  guides(
    color = guide_legend(
      label.position = "right",
      title = NULL,  # Remove the legend title
      override.aes = list(
        size = 5,
        alpha = 1,
        breaks = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
      )
    ),
    size = "none"  # Remove the size legend
  ) +
  labs(size = NULL)   # Remove the legend title for size
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for solving the problem! I have been twisting my head around trying to figure it out.